# Need an HTML view for chat window

Tags: qt

My Qt project needs a chat window similar to Skype. Namely, the chat history window, not where the user inputs his text. I thought of using some kind of HTML view to programmatically add chat text as it comes in from the chat parties.

Some requirements:

1. It has to be formatted nicely, support for CSS I can apply to it..
2. I must have scroll control - e.g. autoscroll to the end of the chat when new chat lines come in, even if I'm currently scrolled up for some reason.
3. it has to allow a full mouse copy, just like skype.

Will QWebView do the hob? I did not see scroll control API, or being able to "append" new text lines. Will I have to re-create and re-submit the HTML using "setHTML" every time a new line comes through?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using either [QTextEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html) or [QTextBrowser](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html).  Both of these widgets have support for HTML (though it may be somewhat limited).  These widgets will allow you to append HTML line-by-line.  They also inherit from QAbstractScrollArea, which provides you with access to their scroll bars.  I'm not sure if they will support CSS, but they do support [Qt's style sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html), which might work for you as an alternative if you can't get CSS to work.  They also provide out-of-the-box copy, cut, paste, undo and redo (though you'll probably want to customize this for your case).